# Possible to install SVGAII drivers on ESX3.5, build 64607 for Windows2k8 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esx

I have ESX3.5, without any of the updates. I installed Windows 2008 R2 SP1 and then installed VMWare tools which defaulted to the standard VGA driver. Graphics performance is horrible. I go to update to the SVGA II drivers found here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Tools\Drivers\video

And I get a driver incompatible for this version of Windows warning. It looks like R2 is compatible with ESX4 or ESX3.5 Update 5. I've read that it is much easier to backup the VMs, install ESX updates and then restore the VMs. This seems like a lot of work. Are there any work arounds? I have no reason to upgrade ESX except for this specific VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm certainly not surprised that you're having problems with such an old version of ESX and such a new version of Windows, and the right course of action would indeed be to update your ESX. But I think you're assuming too much work is ahead of you.

Firstly any time you want to do something such as updating your hypervisor it makes sense to backup your system including VMs, but if you simply update to 3.5U5 this should have very little impact on your system, unless it goes horribly wrong you shouldn't have to restore at all. Why not give it a go, do your backups - that makes sense anyway - and update your host/s - it may be a 20 minute job, certainly it should be anyway.

Best of luck.